# R ggplot2: Replacing aes_string() with aes() and .data[[varname]] when varname may be NULL

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

I am working on updating some older R code to make it use ggplot2's aes() now that aes_string() is deprecated. I admit I don't understand all of the details of tidy evaluation, but from what I do understand it seems like the replacement for aes_string(shape=shapevar) would be aes(shape=.data[[shapevar]]), or possibly aes(shape=!!sym(shapevar)).

The problem with these replacements is that they do not work when shapevar is NULL, as shown in the example below:

```
library('ggplot2')

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(25),y=rnorm(25),othervar=factor(sample(1:3,25,replace=T)))

make_scatter_string <- function(plotdat,outfile,xvar='x',yvar='y',colorvar=NULL,shapevar=NULL) {
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat,aes_string(x=xvar,y=yvar,color=colorvar,shape=shapevar)) + geom_point()
  ggsave(outfile,plt)
}

make_scatter_data <- function(plotdat,outfile,xvar='x',yvar='y',colorvar=NULL,shapevar=NULL) {
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat,aes(x=.data[[xvar]],y=.data[[yvar]],color=.data[[colorvar]],shape=.data[[shapevar]])) + geom_point()
  ggsave(outfile,plt)
}

make_scatter_sym <- function(plotdat,outfile,xvar='x',yvar='y',colorvar=NULL,shapevar=NULL) {
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat,aes(x=!!sym(xvar),y=!!sym(yvar),color=!!sym(colorvar),shape=!!sym(shapevar))) + geom_point()
  ggsave(outfile,plt)
}

make_scatter_string(dat,'test1.png',colorvar='othervar') # Works, aes_string can handle shapevar being NULL
make_scatter_data(dat,'test2.png',colorvar='othervar') # Gives error message "Error in `.data[[NULL]]`: ! Must subset the data pronoun with a string, not NULL."
make_scatter_sym(dat,'test3.png',colorvar='othervar') # Gives error message "Error in `sym()`: ! Can't convert NULL to a symbol."
```

What is the correct way to give aes() a variable like shapevar that may contain the name of a variable in the data or may be NULL? Or is there some other value that should be used to say "don't use this aesthetic" instead of NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414389/12993861) on [How to replace the deprecated ggplot2 function aes_string: accepting an arbitrary number of named strings to specify aesthetic mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74414272/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-ggplot2-function-aes-string-accepting-an-arbitrar/74414389#74414389), a flexible and generalized approach of the one by @r2evans may look like so.

Basically I renamed the functions arguments to the names of the aesthetics and used `...` to allow to pass additional aesthetics and which also works with `NULL`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

make_scatter_sym <- function(plotdat, outfile, x = "x", y = "y", ...) {
  args <- lapply(list(x = x, y = y, ...), function(x) if (!is.null(x)) sym(x))

  plt <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(!!!args)) +
    geom_point()

  ggsave(outfile, plt)

  plt
}

make_scatter_sym(dat, "test1.png", color = "othervar")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

[image]

```r
make_scatter_sym(dat, "test1.png", color = NULL, shape = NULL)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!!! I expanded on this a little further to make a function aes_s() that uses the same approach to serve as a drop-in replacement for aes_string(), so the parent function like make_scatter_sym() could reserve its use of ... for something else if it needed to:
aes_s <- function(...) {
  orig_args <- list(...)
  orig_args <- orig_args[!sapply(orig_args,is.null)]
  return(aes(!!!lapply(orig_args,sym)))
}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add individual `aes(.)` directly based on the value of `is.null(.)`.

```r
make_scatter_data <- function(plotdat, xvar='x', yvar='y', colorvar=NULL, shapevar=NULL) {
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x=.data[[xvar]],y =.data[[yvar]])) + geom_point()
  if (!is.null(colorvar)) plt <- plt + aes(color=.data[[colorvar]])
  if (!is.null(shapevar)) plt <- plt + aes(shape=.data[[shapevar]])
  plt
}
make_scatter_data(dat, colorvar='othervar')
```

[image: ggplot by dot-data, colorvar]

Similarly,

```r
make_scatter_sym <- function(plotdat, xvar='x', yvar='y', colorvar=NULL, shapevar=NULL) {
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x=!!sym(xvar), y=!!sym(yvar))) + geom_point()
  if (!is.null(colorvar)) plt <- plt + aes(color = !!sym(colorvar))
  if (!is.null(shapevar)) plt <- plt + aes(shape = !!sym(shapevar))
  plt
}
make_scatter_sym(dat, shapevar='othervar')
```

[image: ggplot by symbol, shapevar]

Comment: Thanks!! This works, but it seems like a convoluted way to replace something that used to only take one line with aes_string(). It also doesn't seem like it would adapt well when using aes() inside of a geom like geom_point() instead of plot-wide - in that case it would take separate handling for every possible combination of null/non-null. If the point of tidyeval is to make code cleaner and more streamlined, it seems like it would have a shorter way to address this situation (but if it does, I haven't been able to find it).

Comment: I agree with all of your points, I don't (yet) have a more flexible option.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
make_scatter_data <- function(plotdat, outfile, xvar = x, yvar = y,
                              colorvar = NULL, shapevar = NULL) {
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat,
           aes(x={{xvar}}, y={{yvar}}, color={{colorvar}}, shape={{shapevar}})) + 
    geom_point()
  ggsave(outfile,plt)
}


make_scatter_data(dat, "myfile.png")
```

[image]

```
make_scatter_data(dat, "myfile.png", colorvar = othervar)
```

[image]

```
make_scatter_data(dat, "myfile.png", shapevar = othervar)
```

[image]

```
make_scatter_data(dat, "myfile.png", xvar = y, yvar = x, 
                  colorvar = othervar, shapevar = othervar)
```

[image]

---

Or if you want to feed in quoted names:

```
make_scatter_data <- function(plotdat, outfile, xvar = x, yvar = y,
                              colorvar = NULL, shapevar = NULL) {
  xvar = sym(xvar)
  yvar = sym(yvar)
  if(!is.null(colorvar)) colorvar = sym(colorvar)
  if(!is.null(shapevar)) shapevar = sym(shapevar)
  
  plt <- ggplot(plotdat,
                aes(x={{xvar}}, y={{yvar}}, color={{colorvar}}, shape={{shapevar}})) + 
    geom_point()
  plt
  # ggsave(outfile,plt)
}

make_scatter_data(dat, "myfile.png", xvar = "y", yvar = "x", 
                  colorvar = "othervar")
```

Comment: This is a very nice and clean solution. The only major drawback I see with this approach is that all existing code that uses the function would have to be updated to not quote the variable names given as arguments.

Comment: You could use `sym` to convert from quoted names to symbols, but similar to @r2evans' solution, I think you'd need special handling to toggle some aesthetics between NULL and a variable, which can be avoided if you're not using strings.