# Aesthetics by column named with variable, how to use embrace operator in aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2, metaprogramming, rlang

I have a data frame and I want to tell ggplot2 to color according to a column I name with a string variable

```
cubbins <- tibble(x=1:10, y=c(1:5, 1:5), title=rep(c("500 hats", "Oobleck"), 5))
my_col <- "title"

cubbins %>% ggplot(aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=my_col)) + geom_point() ## works, deprecated
cubbins %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=!!my_col)) + geom_point() ## wrong
cubbins %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color={{my_col}})) + geom_point() ## same wrong
cubbins %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=sym(my_col))) + geom_point() ## invalid aesthetics warning
cubbins %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=enquo(my_col))) + geom_point() ## invalid aesthetics warning

cubbins %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=.data[[my_col]])) + geom_point() ## this is what's recommended in the current aes_string documentation
cubbins %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=!!sym(my_col))) + geom_point() ## WORKS, please explain
```

The last version works, but I'm confused about why all the other versions aren't working. Your assistance is appreciated.

wrong version:
[image: plot using embrace incorrectly]
correct version:
[image: correct plot]

For background, `aes_string` is deprecated, but I didn't find any explanation for the proper workaround anywhere in my brief googling.

General refernce: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-metaprogramming.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74414272/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-ggplot2-function-aes-string-accepting-an-arbitrar#string-accepting-an-arbitrar This question is similar, but more complex. It suggests using `sym` in one of the answers, but it's not easy (for me) to see immediately that `!!sym(x)` solves the problem.

Comment: more related info https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/07/ggplot2-version-3-0-0-brings-tidy-evaluation-to-ggplot/

Comment: SO isn't really the right forum for this question, but this is explained in detail in Advanced R ([free online](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/index.html) or [buy it](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Second-Chapman-Hall-CRC-dp-0815384572/dp/0815384572/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)), specifically in the [quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) and [evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html) chapters. Basically, your failed attempts all use non-standard evaluation (NSE); when you're using NSE, things get complicated, but `!!sym(var)` is an appropriate expression in this case.

Answer (score 3):

We can actually use the `aes` function on its own to get a better handle on what's going on.

Essentially, we want something that gives us the same output as:

```r
library(ggplot2)

aes(colour = title)
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `title`
```

Here, the aesthetics `colour` is linked to the *symbol* `title`. But we want to achieve this using a stored, pre-defined character string:

```r
my_col <- "title"
```

Previously, we could simply have used `aes_string`:

```r
aes_string(color = my_col)
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `title`
#> Warning message:
#> `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0.
#> i Please use tidy evaluation ideoms with `aes()`
```

This works, mapping `colour` to the symbol `title`, but as the warning tells us, this function is deprecated.

For completeness, let's look at `aes(color = my_col)`, which you sensibly didn't even try

```r
aes(color = my_col)
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `my_col`
```

Of course, the `aes` function has simply captured the *symbol* `my_col`, which won't work because you have no column called `my_col` in your data frame.

Now we move on to the attempts using unquoting. Both the `!!` and `{{` operators evaluate their operand and inline it in the AST, so they both evaluate to the *string* `"title"`, not the *symbol* `title`. Note the quotation marks:

```r
aes(color = !!my_col)
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> "title"

#> aes(color = {{my_col}})
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> "title"
```

This means that all the points on your plot will be given the same colour, since they are all mapped to a single string, which will just be recycled to the length of the data.

You might think that `sym` or `enquo` should work, but the problem is that without an unquoting operator, the whole *unevaluated expression* is captured. Look what happens with `sym` and `enquo`:

```r
aes(color = sym(my_col))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `sym(my_col)`

aes(color = enquo(my_col))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `enquo(my_col)`
```

Now we are trying to map colour to a *call*, which doesn't even make sense, and `ggplot` will just throw an error. We need our mapping to be to a symbol, not a call. However, we can evaluate and inline `sym(my_col)` using the `!!` operator to get the symbol `title`. If we use `enquo` then we will again get a string as the output of the evaluation, and the `{{` operator only works on names, not calls, so the solution is:

```r
aes(color = !!sym(my_col))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `title`
```

I actually prefer this to the recommended method, which results in:

```r
aes(color = .data[my_col])
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `.data[my_col]`
```

This works perfectly well, but only because `ggplot` recognises the `.data` pronoun and treats it differently.

There are other options. Anything that gets us the correct symbol will work:

```r
aes(color = !!str2lang(my_col))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `title`

aes(color = !!as.name(my_col))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> `title`
```

And it's even possible to build the aesthetic mapping from scratch using only base R functions if you really wanted to:

```r
ggplot(cubbins, 
  structure(
    list(colour = structure(
      `attr<-`(call("~", str2lang(my_col)), ".Environment", .GlobalEnv), 
      class = c("quosure", "formula")), 
    x = structure(
      `attr<-`(call("~", str2lang("x")), ".Environment", .GlobalEnv), 
      class = c("quosure", "formula")),
    y = structure(
      `attr<-`(call("~", str2lang("y")), ".Environment", .GlobalEnv), 
      class = c("quosure", "formula"))
    ), 
    class = "uneval")) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, lucid answer.

Comment: Extra points for showing how the return value of the `aes` function can be used to unravel what the interpreter is doing.